# find page and assign a value to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel file and there are 20 sheets

I need to search and find several sheet on my excel that  want and add email to M1 Cell

Could you please help me.

Comment: Explain detail. Put some sample data. Do research by yourself. Show us your effort then we will help you.

Comment: Hi Harun I tried to write as follows but it gets error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
döngü:
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "ABC" Then
    Sheets("ABC").Select
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "abc@hotmail.com"
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "ABC2" Then
    Sheets("ABC2").Select
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "abc2@hotmail.com"
    GoTo döngü:
pass:
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "mail assign done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use below sub.

```
Sub WriteEmail()
On Error GoTo HarunErrHandler

    Sheets("ABC").Range("M1") = "abc@hotmail.com"
    Sheets("ABC2").Range("M1") = "abc2@hotmail.com"

Exit Sub
HarunErrHandler:
MsgBox "No such sheet found.", vbInformation, "Info"
'MsgBox("Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error")
End Sub
```

Comment: You do not need to activate sheet.

Comment: Hi Harun,
Thanks for your answer but if there is no ABC sheet it gets error.

Comment: Then just use error handler to get error message saying "No such" sheet. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Harun i made a little change with your comments.

Following code worked well.

Thank you so much

```
Sub WriteEmail()
    Sheets("ABC").Range("M1") = "abc@hotmail.com"
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("ABC2").Range("M1") = "abc2@hotmail.com"
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("ABC3").Range("M1") = "abc3@hotmail.com"
    On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox ("process done")
End Sub
```